# unsupported proxy in HTTPClient

Tags: ruby

I want to use Ruby httpclient to make requests. I tried to implement this code:

```
def submit!
    http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

    request = HTTPClient.new(url)
    request.basic_auth('username', 'pass')
    request['content-type'] = 'application/xml'
    request['cache-control'] = 'no-cache'
    request.body = request_body

    response = http.request(request).body
    response = Response.new(response)
    check_for_approved_response(response)

    response
  end
```

But I get error:

```
unsupported proxy https://staging.gate.some_address.net/process/3ab20f2ddbe78ab8be9f5a9645c1010330dc868f
```

Can you recommend some solution how to fix it?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

make sure ruby can see and read /etc/resolv.conf and that you don't have HTTP_PROXY env variable set. Also check that your ssl isn't using a non-standard ssl port.

Answer (score 0):

Run echo $HTTP_PROXY on your terminal. If you see any value, its not good. You'll have to unset that variable.

See - https://github.com/savonrb/savon/issues/123#issuecomment-620825

Answer (score 0):

> https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/2.1.5.2/HTTPClient
>
> Accessing resources through HTTP proxy. You can use environment variable 'http_proxy' or 'HTTP_PROXY' instead.
>
> `clnt = HTTPClient.new('http://myproxy:8080')`

So in your code `request = HTTPClient.new(url)` is putting target url as proxy of HTTPClient.  (It is indeed a little confusing when you come from net/http)